# SOLVED: Microsoft Access Error 2282 when acOutputReport to acFormatPDF

Tags: ms-access

I have a routine that has been emailing reports for years.  It stopped working on just one PC among several at one of my clients.  All PC's run the same front end ACCDB file in 2013 RunTime.

I've isolated the issue from everything else I can think of in the following simple function.  I can comment out either of the OutputTo lines to run it, and it fails on acFormatPDF with Error 2282, but not with acFormatHTML.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP8r1.png)

Report name and path are valid as they work with acFormatHTML.

All references are the same across all machines.

[References:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9nBg.png)

What to check next?

```
Function TestToFILE()
On Error GoTo TestToPDF_ERR

    'Works
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "__RptTpl", acFormatHTML, "C:\PermitW\Temp\__Rpt_Tpl.HTM", False

    'Does Not work
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "__RptTpl", acFormatPDF, "C:\PermitW\Temp\__Rpt_Tpl.PDF", False   

Exit Function
      
TestToPDF_ERR:

    MsgBox "TestToPDF_ERR: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Function
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/run-time-error-2282-exporting-report-to-email-in-pdf-format.289422/. It points to an MS help page for DoCmd. Close to the bottom it states that you my need to install an add-in.

Comment: Yes I saw that but it seemed to be referencing Access 2007.  This is 2013 runtime and the other PC's do not have this add-in but it runs successfully.  I will check to see if adding it through runtime (probably via code) helps.

Comment: So the issue is not the code but possibly the install of Access Runtime.

Comment: Your answer was a great clue.  I uninstalled and reinstalled the 2013 RunTime and it resolved the issue.  No Add-In required! Thanks!